# ¿Cómo se llama la característica que tiene el español, y otros idiomas, por la que las vocales siempre se pronuncian de la misma manera?

Tags: definiciones, vocales, fonética

Me gustaría saber cómo se llama cuando los sonidos de las vocales escritas suenan siempre de la misma manera al pronunciarlas.

Una vez me topé con la definición, pero esta vez no tuve mucha suerte en Google, y creí conveniente hacer la pregunta acá.

Comment: Nota: Hay una pregunta relacionada, acerca de [por qué el español se pronuncia como se escribe](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/10178/5481)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se llama lenguaje con **ortografía fonológica** (English: [phonemic orthography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonemic_orthography))

> En una ortografía fonológica cada [grafema](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grafema) se corresponde con un
>   [fonema](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonema).

Comment: Ortografía Fonética o Fonológica, sería entonces la definición mas apropiada, ya que el uso del termino transparente podría ser algo ambiguo.

Answer (score 5):

No estoy seguro de si hay otros términos para referirse al mismo hecho, pero yo lo he visto escrito como idioma u ortografía «**transparentes**». Es decir, que posee un sistema ortográfico en el que existe un alto grado de correspondencia entre los grafemas (símbolos escritos) y los fonemas (sonidos pronunciados). Esto no se reduce a las vocales, sino que abarca también a las consonantes. El español, el ruso o el italiano están entre esos idiomas. El francés e inglés se consideran más «opacos».

Hay un gran artículo sobre el tema (lo siento, en inglés) titulado [The Transparency of Spanish Orthography](http://lrc.salemstate.edu/aske/courses/readings/The_Transparency_of_Spanish_Orthography_By_Ian_Mackenzie.htm), del que traduzco una parte de la introducción:

> A diferencia de sus homólogos inglés o francés, el sistema ortográfico
>   del español está diseñado para expresar lo más transparentemente
>   posible las relaciones sonido-símbolo. De hecho, la mayoría de los
>   expertos institucionales del idioma español tratan a la ortografía
>   como una rama de la fonología descriptiva. Por ejemplo, en su *Esbozo
>   de una Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española*, la Real Academia
>   Española incluye un capítulo sobre la ortografía en la sección que
>   trata sobre la fonología. El párrafo de introducción de ese capítulo
>   contiene la siguiente afirmación reveladora: «En este [capítulo]...
>   veremos... el sistema establecido por oposiciones [fonéticas]
>   distintivas, esto es, especificamos un solo símbolo para cada fonema».

Más info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_depth y https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonemic_orthography

Comment: +1 Es interesante la posibilidad de que el español incorpore mas "letras" o simbolos  al alfabeto, por ejemplo para el sonido "ch"