# ¿Por qué el español se pronuncia como se escribe?

Tags: historia, ortografía, fonología

¿Por qué el español, a diferencia de otros lenguajes como el inglés, se escribe como se pronuncia (o se pronuncia como se escribe)?

En mis tiempos de estudiante, durante una clase de lengua salió esta pregunta y creo recordar que la respuesta es que en España convivieron durante mucho tiempo tres culturas, prácticamente representadas por sus tres religiones: cristianos, judíos y musulmanes. Por aquel entonces tanto el árabe como el hebreo tenían lenguaje escrito, pero no así el español. Debido a la necesidad de traducir de un idioma a otro se forzó la creación del lenguaje escrito para el español como una especie de "anotaciones" y por eso el español escrito es una representación fonética del hablado, y se puede decir que el español se escribe como se habla.

Lo que no sé seguro es si esto es cierto o no. No consigo encontrar ninguna referencia que lo avale. ¿Alguien sabe cuál es la razón de que el español tenga una **mayor correspondencia entre símbolos escritos y fonemas** (prácticamente casi idéntica) que otros lenguajes?

Comment: Tal vez este artículo pueda servir para aclarar algunas cosas acerca de las *"tres culturas y las religiones correspondientes": http://revistamito.com/historia-de-la-lengua-espanola-ii-fonetica-y-morfosintaxis/ El Español no siempre se leía como se escribía.

Comment: @JersonZuleta, interesante artículo. No entiendo la referencia a las tres culturas. Evidentemente el lenguaje ha evolucionado. Creo que en un principio daba igual como escribías algo (casi como se escribe ahora en los mensajes de texto, internet y demás), pero no sé hasta qué punto eso está relacionado con la necesidad de crear una forma escrita de un lenguaje hablado.

Comment: La referencia a las tres culturas radica a que el Español sí ha tenido un lenguaje escrito—— muchos dirían que la forma en como está escrito el poema del Mio Cid no es Español, por el mero hecho de que no es el Español moderno como lo conocemos. Hmmmm dudo de que "daba igual cómo escribías algo", las palabras tenían forma definida y su fonética simplemente varió, lo cual en consecuencia hizo que su escritura también cambiase.

Comment: A lo que me refiero es que podrías ver escrito "tornava la cabeça e estava" como "tornaba la cavesa e estaba" (siguiendo la referencia al Mio Cid, que claro que es español, pero antiguo). Una cosa es que el español haya tenido lenguaje escrito casi desde el principio y otra que también haya tenido gramática definida desde el principio... En la primera parte del articulo de tu enlace parece que el castellano surgió alrededor del 1050. Quizá eso nos de más pistas para responder la pregunta.

Comment: "tornaba la cavesa e estaba" Seguro, pero no creo que en la misma época. Es claro en el ejemplo que dan como la transformación de *cabeça* dió a lugar *cabeza*, *cabesa*...

Comment: Pues eso es de lo que no estoy completamente seguro. De ser así, aunque no da una respuesta, por lo menos sirve para descartar la hipótesis que presentaba en mi pregunta.

Comment: @JersonZuleta "en el manuscrito del Mío Cid aparecen tanto «veluntad» como «voluntad»", extraído del enlace de la respuesta de Walter. Por lo que sí parece que había ciertas inconsistencias en la misma época.

Comment: Otros idiomas también se *pronuncian como se escriben* (el polaco y el alemán, por mencionar dos que son de distintas familias). No creo que sea algo propio del español.

Comment: @c.p. y cuál es la razón? Similar a la del español?

Comment: Me parece que sería más apropriado preguntar por qué otras lenguas no tienen ortografía casi fonética.

Comment: @Aprendedor, es una buena pregunta, pero estaría un poco fuera del ámbito de este sitio (que es sobre el español, no sobre idiomas en general). Creo que sería una pregunta completamente válida en el _stack_ de [linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Quisiera dar mi opinión con respecto a los sonidos de las vocales en inglés, una particularidad, que nos favorece a los hispanohablantes, es que en la mayoría los monosílabos guardan una gran similitud con nuestras vocales, ej rat. melt, sit, moth, put. Por supuesto que hay excepciones, en inglés siempre las hay, es difícil aprender una regla.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El desarollo de la ortografía española se debe, en gran parte, a la influencia de la Real Academia Española.  Antes de la modernización de la ortografía, había mayor divergencia entre el idioma escrito y el idioma oral.  ([ver Wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ortograf%C3%ADa_del_espa%C3%B1ol#Historia))

Aunque Wikipedia asevera que la ortografía española no es fonética, sí es casi fonética en contraste con el inglés.  En el inglés, una palabra como "caught" mantiene el mismo deletreo de lo que tenía hace siglos, cuando la pronunciación parecía más como anglosajón.

El inglés nunca ha sufrido una modernización semejante al español, por varias razones.  Y la divergencia entre el idioma oral y escrito continúa evolucionando.

Comment: +1, pero no hay ninguna explicación para el "fenómeno" de la ortografía fonética. Hay más de una causa y es imposible rastrearlas? Supongo que puede ser así, si incluso hay un debate abierto acerca de si la ortografía española es fonética o no, como demuestras con la referencia al artículo de wikipedia.

Comment: No hay ningún debate. No es "fonética". Peor aún considerando las diferencias regionales. El sonido de la /b/ se puede escribir tanto con _v_ como con _b_, y en latinoamérica, el sonido de la /s/ se puede escribir con tanto _s_, _c_ y _z_ (en el artículo de wikipedia hay más ejemplos). Una ortografía "fonética" no permitiría esto y sería un mapeo de una letra a un sonido.

Comment: @clinch, cierto, pero yo pronuncio _baca_ y _vaca_ exactamente igual. Y si veo escrito _cabeza_ y _Kaveza_ las voy a pronunciar igual (a diferencia del inglés donde _tier_ está fonéticamente cerca de _tear_ que de _lier_)

Comment: En lo de Wikipedia dicen lo siguiente "El primer intento de dotar de un código gráfico sistemático data del reinado de Alfonso X, que intentaría ajustar las diversas soluciones adoptadas por sus predecesores a un criterio fundamentalmente fonográfico."

Comment: Cierto, ese párrafo me parece clave, junto al de "La ortografía real intentó reflejar con notable fidelidad las propiedades fonológicas del habla de la época" y "correspondencia estrecha entre fonema y grafema propuesta por la obra alfonsina."

Comment: A pesar de que mi pregunta puede pecar del "La afirmación de que la ortografía del español es principalmente fonográfica (o fonética) es tan extendida como errónea" creo que el "Si bien **la correspondencia entre grafía y lenguaje hablado es predecible a partir de la escritura** —es decir, un hablante competente es capaz de determinar inequívocamente la pronunciación estimada correcta para casi cualquier texto—, [aunque] no sucede así a la inversa", junto con las explicaciones del enlace **responde a mi pregunta**, por eso he decidido aceptar la respuesta.

Comment: La diferencia entre lo que dice Diego y lo que dice @clinch se asemeja a la diferencia entre un homomorfismo y un isomorfismo.  Esto es un poco abstracto, pero es la misma idea.

Answer (score 12):

Aunque el español como lengua respeta bastante el principio fonético en comparación con otras lenguas en especial indoeuropeas:

> La afirmación de que la ortografía del español es principalmente fonográfica (o fonética) es tan extendida como errónea. Una ortografía fonográfica tiende a respetar el principio fonémico según el cual el conjunto de fonemas de una lengua y el conjunto de letras con las que ésta se escribe deben corresponderse biunívocamente, es decir, para cada letra debe haber un solo fonema y para cada fonema debe haber una sola letra.

<sub>[Fuente](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ortograf%C3%ADa_del_espa%C3%B1ol#Regularidad_e_irregularidad_ortogr.C3.A1fica)</sub>

La razón de este fenómeno es que en sus primeros años de uso, cuando el idioma castellano convivía con otras lenguas en la península ibérica (como vascuence, portugués, catalán, etc.), el lenguaje fue evolucionando sin una grafía impresa.

Alfonso X fue el primero en intentar dotar de un código gráfico al idioma. El criterio que se adoptó para elaborar esta grafía fue **fonológico** (reflejando las propiedades fonológicas del habla de la época). Este enfoque fonológico fue seguido por *Elio Antonio de Nebrija* en su publicación de la *Reglas de orthographia*, que ya aparte de criterios fonológicos incluía criterios etimológicos para la representación gráfica de ciertas palabras.

<sub>[Fuente](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ortograf%C3%ADa_del_espa%C3%B1ol#Per.C3.ADodo_alfons.C3.AD)</sub>

En 1713 fue fundada la Real Academia Española, para "fijar, de acuerdo con el ideal sistemático de la época, la pureza de la lengua". El ideal de la época, debido al *afrancesamiento* de las instituciones culturales tras el acceso al trono de Felipe de Anjou como Felipe V promovió "la etimología y la pronunciación histórica" frente al principio fonetista para representar el lenguaje.

<sub>[Fuente](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ortograf%C3%ADa_del_espa%C3%B1ol#La_fundaci.C3.B3n_de_la_Academia)</sub>

Por eso la elaboración de la grafía escrita del lenguaje ha evolucionado de intentar un enfoque fonético a uno más orientado el sentido etimológico e histórico, otorgando al español una menor *profundidad ortográfica* (mayor correspondencia entre el lenguaje escrito y el hablado) que otras lenguas "hermanas".

Comment: Las muchas excepciones incluidas más adelante con tu primera fuente realmente debieran poner fin al mito de que tenga el castellano una ortografía puramente fonética.

Comment: @tchrist, yo creo que lo hace. Hice una afirmación muy exagerada al decir que "se escribe y pronuncia igual" cuando redacté la pregunta, como muchos me hicieron ver. Entre respuestas y comentarios se puede ver 1) que tal afirmación no es cierta y 2) la evolución de la gramática escrita, que explica ciertos fenómenos del lenguaje. A pesar de todo me parecía que había que rebuscar entre respuestas y comentarios para tener una imagen completa, y decidí facilitar una respuesta que englobase tanto la evolución de fonológico a etimológico-histórico a la par que dejase claro que no es fonética.

Answer (score 2):

Este alfabeto está hecho para el latín, por eso hay que forzar las letras en otros idiomas donde a e  i o u no alcanzan. **ESTA ES LA RAZÓN: Porque el español no se apartó mucho del latín original PARA EL CUAL ESTÁ HECHO EL ABC Dario.**

Because the ABCD is the latin alphabet, and Spanish is so much similar to latin. But because in some part of history almost every western language was represented by ABCD letters, they had to make mixes that sounded barely similar in some cases, in Spanish there were only few adaptations at difference from English for example that has so many adaptations to be able to work with the Latin writting system.

Comment: +1 El alfabeto latino se desarroló para representar el latín. Parece lógico que los idiomas no latinos han tenido más dificultades para representar sonidos mediante el alfabeto latino.

Answer (score 1):

La pregunta envuelve una afirmación que no es correcta.

El español no se pronuncia como se escribe más que otros idiomas. Lo que pasa es que nosotros, los hispanohablantes, estamos acostumbrados desde que aprendemos a leer a "convertir" tales dibujos en cuales sonidos. Pero esto es lo mismo que ocurre con los niños que aprenden como lengua materna el sueco o el japonés o cualquier otro.

¿Qué pasa con la "letra" *ch*? ¿Se pronuncia una c seguida de una h?

¿Y la *x*?

En español tenemos tres letras para el sonido inicial de la palabra *casa*: c, k y qu, y nótese esa "qu" que no es precisamente una q seguida de una u.

Y en Latinoamérica tenemos tres letras para el sonido inicial de *sopa*: s, c y z, que no son para nada los mismos de Castilla. O sea, en Chile, en Perú y en México "sopa", "cena" y "zampa" empiezan con el mismo sonido, pero se escriben com tres letras distintas. Mientras que en Madrid la primera suena distinto que las dos segundas.

Nadie pronuncia la primera sílaba de la palabra *infierno* con el sonido *n*. Se acerca más a una *m*, aunque tampoco es exactamente ese sonido.

Se escribe "abuelo", ¿cómo se pronuncia? ¿Es eso una *b* igual que la de "barco"?

Cuando un angloparlante (que hace chasquear las letras T poniendo la lengua atrás de los dientes) escucha a un colombiano pronunciar la palabra "tomate" se pregunta, ¿por qué estos tipos no pronuncian tal como está escrito?

A lo que quiero llegar es a los siguiente: las personas que no hablamos y leemos inglés desde pequeños consideramos ridículo que ellos usen las letras "through" para escribir lo que se pronuncia "zrú". Pero, al mismo tiempo, las personas que no hablan y escriben español desde niños también encuentran ridículo que escribamos "chancho" cuando queremos decir "xañxo", con todas las dificultades que esto implica al aprender el español como segunda lengua.

Comment: "Nadie pronuncia la primera sílaba de la palabra infierno con el sonido n." No sé de dónde eres, pero por lo menos aquí en Bogotá, Colombia, puedo distinguir claramente el sonido de la n en la palabra *infierno*.

Comment: Entiendo que no es del todo correcto decir que se escribe como se pronuncia, o para empezar no habría letra "H" que es muda. Sin embargo, sí que es una legua con una mayor relación fonética entre el lenguaje hablado y el escrito. Parece que sí es evidente que [unos lenguajes tienen mayor relación o *profundidad ortográfica* que otros](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/635). [Esta respuesta](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/643) en el Stack de lingüistas apunta al lenguaje español como un ejemplo de una relación _casi_ directa entre símbolos y fonemas (**ortografía fonética**).

Comment: Wow, Diego. Me quitaste la idea de la mente. Precisamente iba a aclarar lo de la profundidad ortográfica. El Inglés tiene una profundidad mucho mayor a la del Español—— Lo que dice Rodrigo de que ellos pronuncian tal como está escrito también, lo dudo mucho. Pon una palabra no común que probablemente ellos nunca hayan escuchado o visto, un hablante del Español se acercará muchísimo más que lo haría un angloparlante a la correcta pronunciación.

Comment: Quedé picado con este tema. No puedo negar que ambos tienen razón, pero quiero estar en desacuerdo de alguna forma. Ya se me va a ocurrir... Creo que eso de acercarse a la *correcta pronunciación* es medio ambiguo. Habría que cotejar con las tablas fonéticas, que después de todo son arbitrarias...

Comment: Ah, Jerson: si le dictas a un hablante de otro idioma "infierno" (sin conocer la palabra y sin exagerar la pronunciación) va a escribir "imfierno".

Comment: "Creo que eso de acercarse a la correcta pronunciación es medio ambiguo." Es un ejemplo muy común cuando algún angloparlante del Reino Unido con un acento fuerte y marcado pronuncia una palabra que se pronuncia diferente a como lo hacen en EEUU; aún cuando ambos conocen la palabra, la fonética de cada uno no siempre corresponde a la escritura de la misma... la profundidad ortográfica tiene mucha influencia en idiomas con una gran profundidad (valga la redundancia).

Comment: Eso depende de quién lo diga, repito, por lo menos aquí donde yo vivo, la pronunciación hace clara el sonido de la *n* sin exagerar. Se dice que en la capital de Colombia no se tiene acento (lo cual es incorrecto, todos tenemos acento), pero se refiere más al hecho de la pronunciación más clara y más fácil de entender. Si no estoy mal, creo que Costa Rica (no sabría qué regiones) también está dentro de los países donde la pronunciación es más clara que en otros lados.

Comment: Hace muchísimos años, cuando yo estudiaba estas cosas, nos decían que la forma más neutral de español se daba en la variante dialectal llamada "Español del Pacífico", que incluía hablantes desde Centroamérica hasta Perú, sobre todo este último país. Los chilenos podemos reconocer fácilmente el sonsonete de los colombianos, y también creemos que que nuestro dialecto no tiene acento.

Comment: Me dolieron los votos en contra.

Comment: @Rodrigo Por tu dolor no te otorgo otro voto en contra, tu respuesta deja mucho que desear

Comment: No me parece mala tu respuesta @Rodrigo. No entiendo por que los puntos negativos. Votar como no es util la respuesta no me parece apropiado cuando lo que dices no creo que sea incorrecto, de hecho para mi la respuesta es util

Comment: @Diego   ¿De donde saca que la "n" de "infierno" no se pronuncia? ¿o que la "b" cambia si es "abuelo" o "barco"? la realidad es que hay una gran **correlación** entre los signos escritos y el sonido: por ejemplo la "a" siempre se pronuncia "a". Cuando ves una palabra en español que le es a uno desonocida es clara la pronunciación a realizar, no como en inglés que no es evidente.

Comment: ¿El problema de "abuelo" y "barco" no es que "b" tiene distintos alófonos aun siendo el mismo fonema? Parece bastante intuitivo que el sonido de una letra va a ser algo distinto dependiendo de los sonidos contiguos, pero son variaciones sutiles.

Answer (score 1):

La historia es complicada, y hay muchos factores en juego. Pero el factor principal es este: en España (también en Italia) la escritura alcanzó un nivel de difusión masivo relativamente tarde; así, al momento de establecerse una ortografía estandar, la pronunciación también estaba bastante fijada, y luego no ocurrieron cambios importantes. En Inglaterra, por el contrario, la ortografía (que en un principio sí era "fonética") se estandarizó más temprano, antes de que la lengua hablada experimentara cambios importantes en la pronunciación, especialmente con las **vocales** (el "[great vowel shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift)").

[Aquí](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/637/) hay una pregunta similar sobre el idioma italiano.

Answer (score 1):

Hay que distinguir entre los conceptos de “lengua” y “habla”. Todo este hilo acerca de si el español tiene o no una ortografía fonética hace referencia al concepto “lengua”, por tanto todos los argumentos referidos a cómo se pronuncia el fonema “s” en Méjico, etc. no vienen a cuento. Eso es “habla”.
Lo que es indudable es que un hispanohablante siempre sabe cómo se pronuncia cualquier palabra de su idioma, la conozca o no. Y un inglés no. Esa lengua no tiene normas precisas para trasladar grafía a sonido. El español sí. En inglés Hay que conocer en muchos casos cómo se pronuncia la palabra en concreto, y muchas veces, además, el contexto. “Lead” se leerá /li:d/ o /led/ según queramos decir “dirigir” o “plomo”. La combinación “ea” es una pesadilla, y se puede pronunciar /i:/ en “sea”, /e/ en “bread”, parecido a /ia/ en “near”, parecido a /e:/ en “heard”...
Esto jamás ocurre en español. Cierto que tenemos varias grafías para algunos fonemas, como b/v, c/z, g/j, c/qu/k, i/y, pero hay normas estrictas sobre su uso fonético. Distinto es que ortográficamente dudemos entre víbora/vívora/bívora/bíbora: siempre se leerá igual. El euskera ha solucionado en gran parte este problema aprovechando que su normalización batúa fue mucho más reciente y aprovechó todas las ventajas.
Vale, el español no es una lengua absolutamente fonética, pues nuestras grafías no coinciden con los fonemas, como en ninguna lengua. Pero sí está dotada de un conjunto de reglas ortográficas que le permiten al lector saber con toda exactitud y sin ambigüedad cómo se pronuncia una palabra. Y eso es un grandísima ventaja.

Answer (score 0):

Esta pregunta me ha rondado la cabeza casi desde que empecé a estudiar inglés y a romperme los cuernos con su pronunciación, para la que soy muy malo.

Así, el inglés tiene muchos sonidos vocálicos diferentes y aún más formas de representar esos sonidos de forma escrita, a menudo ambiguamente y sin una regla clara que permita diferenciar cada caso sin recurrir directamente a un diccionario con alfabeto fonético internacional. Ejemplos:

> *t**ea**l* [t**iː**l]
>
> *m**ea**d* [m**iː**d]
>
> *st**ea**d* [st**e**d]

No soy lingüista y no puedo argumentar lo siguiente, pero en una ocasión una profesora de inglés (de California) me dijo que el motivo de esto era que el inglés había incorporado (constantemente) muchas palabras de otros idiomas (incluyendo galés, escocés, danés...) sin alterar las formas de escritura y pronunciación originales. Otros idiomas, como el castellano, fueron más prolijos a la hora de adaptar y normalizar los extranjerismos.

Comment: El español ha recibido tantas influencias como el inglés, y su pronunciación ha ido evolucionando, mientras que su escritura se va quedando siempre atrás. En español, igual que en inglés, lo que escribimos no es lo que pronunciamos.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Trataré de verificarla, pero me parece que lo que te contó tu profesora va a ser casi tan difícil de verificar como lo que el mío me contó para explicar la relación fonética del español. A mi me pasa como a ti. Yo nunca presté la debida atención a la pronunciación y ahora me arrepiento. Cada vez que quiero decirle "Mira!" a mi sobrino Luke (_Look! Luke_) me siento un incompetente total. Ya casi siempre uso "watch" en lugar de "look".

Comment: Esto me parece bien, intuitivamente, pero no sé si es la respuesta.  Lo que sí sé es que @diego el inglés es un idioma híbrido.  Véase "Historical and Social Evolution of the English Language", Nilanko Mallik.

Answer (score -3):

Para responder la pregunta, esto se cumple en gran medida para todos los idiomas del planeta Tierra. De no ser así no se podrían escribir en ningún idioma. Lo que sucede es que cada idioma tiene una particular forma de pronunciar sus vocales y vocablos. Además cada estructura u oración no tienen los mismos significados que en el español, depende de la situación y circunstancias de que se hable.

Si presta un poco de atención a la pronunciación de las vocales en inglés y lo compara con cómo se pronuncia esa vocal dentro de una palabra observará lo cierto de lo que le expongo humildemente en estas líneas. Por ejemplo la vocal '**a**' se pronuncia "**ei**" en inglés, por eso la palabra "día" (*day*) se pronuncia "dei", pero va acompañado de la fonética característica de los habitantes de esa región, por eso sabemos si la está pronunciando un norteamericano, un inglés, un alemán, un latino, un francés etc.

Comment: En completo desacuerdo con esto. En inglés Tough, Bough, Cough y Dough se escriben prácticamente igual, pero hay una diferencia en pronunciación entre ellas. Más claro: _here_ and _there_.  Por mucha atención que pongas a la pronunciación de _here_, la de _there_ la tienes que escuchar para conocerla. Aún más: great, meat y threat. Fear, Pear, Dear, Bear. No por prestar atención y comparar, como sugieres, se aprende o deduce la pronunciación de palabras "similares". El español, en cambio, tiene una menor profundidad ortográfica que sí puede permitir hacerlo.